# How to put the result of an executed bash command inside a double quote?

Tags: bash, terminal

Let's say I need to run a command on the terminal:

```
elasticdump \
  --s3AccessKeyId "${$access_key_id}" \
  --s3SecretAccessKey "${access_key_secret}" \
  --input=localhost:123/my_index/ \
  --output "s3://${bucket_name}/${file_name}.json"
```

In which, `access_key_id` and `access_key_secret` are the AWS credentials that need to be put in a double quote.

To get the credentials, I run a program, let's name it `get-cred`:

```
get-cred --type=b info
```

```
get-cred --type=a info
```

When run individually in the command line, each line would print out the secret key and ID, without the double quotes.

How do I put them inside double quotes and use them in the `elasticdump` command?

---

Update with more details:

The outputs of `get-cred` are printed in a single line.

For example:

```
get-cred --type=a info
```

would print out

```
AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
```

and

```
get-cred --type=b info
```

would print out:

```
wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

Example keys taken from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html

Comment: Important conceptual distinction: Insofar as they're meaningful to the parsing process, quotes are _syntax_. Literal quotes in your data don't substitute for semantic quotes in your syntax being missing; they're two entirely different things and orthogonal to each other.

Comment: That said -- can you show me a sanitized example of what `get-cred`'s output looks like? Substitute other content for your real secrets, but the values should be close enough to show the format (so if there are any interesting special characters in the output, they should be there in the sample; if you don't know if something qualifies as interesting, include it).

Comment: ...are the values printed to a single line, separated by spaces? To two separate lines, thus separated by a newline? Something else?

Comment: "\"$access_key_id\""

Comment: @RamanSailopal, absolutely not. That's adding **literal** quotes, the OP needs **syntactic** quotes.

Comment: @RamanSailopal the outputs of `get-cred` are printed in a single line.

For example:

```
get-cred --type=a info
```

would print out

```
AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
```

and 

```
get-cred --type=b info
```

would print out:

```
wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

Example keys taken from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html

Comment: @Katie, great, then. `elasticdump --s3AccessKeyId "$(get-cred --type=a info)" --s3SecretAccessKey "$(get-cred --type=b info)"` -- the quotes that surround the `$(...)` are the only kind of quotes you need.

Comment: Something like `"$(get-cred --type=a info)"`?

Comment: Oh that works! Thanks! @CharlesDuffy